# ¿Como detectar eventos "escuchas" cuando la página va a recargar o cambiar de página con javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, navegador-web

bueno por motivos de seguridad quiero implementar en mi sistema prevención cuando por error estas saliendo de un formulario sin guardar cambios, ya sea que diste "atrás", al botón salir de la página, recargaste página o incluso si diste cerrar pestaña de la página.

Un ejemplo son como los mensajes como los que salen en facebook:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi sistema es en .NET y con vistas parciales, incluso por si das click en el menu y guardaste cambios porque se te olvido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que función en javascript jquery podría utilizar para evaluar que la página va a cambiar o a cerrarse?
¿o hay algún otro método?

Answer (score 1):

❏ **Poner**

Con jQuery, puedes añadir un escucha con:

```js
$(window).on("beforeunload", function(e) {
    return '¿Cancelar todo?';
});
```

❏ **Quitar**

Para quitarlo:

```
$(window).off("beforeunload");
```

Véase un ejemplo en [*JSFiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/gtagw0vL/).